# Как наложить диалоговое окно поверх текущей программы?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside6

Мне требуется наложить диалоговое окно (виджет, допустим **`вы уверены? /да и нет`**) поверх основного окна отцентрировав и  затемнив его (допустим полупрозрачным серым цветом, всё в том же окне).

Как это можно реализовать?

Мой код:

```
import os
import sys

from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QSize, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import QPixmap
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QFormLayout, QFrame, QGridLayout,
                               QMainWindow, QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QSpacerItem,
                               QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout)





class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        if not Form.objectName():
            Form.setObjectName(u"Form")
        Form.resize(417, 120)
        self.gridLayout_2 = QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName(u"gridLayout_2")
        self.label = QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        self.label.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 50))
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 2)

        self.pushButton = QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")

        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.pushButton_2 = QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(u"pushButton_2")

        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 1, 1, 1, 1)


        self.retranslateUi(Form)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Form", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"\u0412\u044b \u0443\u0432\u0435\u0440\u0435\u043d\u044b?", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"\u0414\u0430", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"\u041d\u0435\u0442", None))
    # retranslateUi


class Widget(QWidget, Ui_Form): # пример виджета
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)





class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(808, 510)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")

        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")

        self.frame = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setObjectName(u"frame")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        self.image_label = QLabel(alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.image_label.setObjectName(u"image_label")
        self.image_label.setPixmap(QPixmap("head3.png"))
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        lay.addWidget(self.image_label)

        self.widget = QWidget(self.image_label)
        self.widget.setObjectName(u"widget")
        # +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        self.formLayout = QFormLayout(self.widget)  # - (self.frame)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName(u"formLayout")

        self.pushButton = QPushButton()  # - (self.frame)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QSize(50, 30))
        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777214, 16777215))
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.pushButton)

        self.verticalSpacer = QSpacerItem(20, 250, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.formLayout.setItem(0, QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.verticalSpacer)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Test", None))


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setupUi(self)





Stylesheet = """
#centralwidget {
    background-color:  rgb(37, 237, 37);
}
#frame {
    background-color:  rgb(37, 37, 237);
}

#pushButton {
    background-color: rgba(233, 33, 33, 0.7);
    color: #bfbfbf;
}
#image_label {
    background-color:  rgb(137, 137, 237);
}
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)  # +++

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не уверен, что правильно понял, то что вы хотите сделать.

Класс [**QDialog**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#details) является базовым классом диалоговых окон.

```
import os
import sys
'''
from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QSize, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import QPixmap
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QFormLayout, QFrame, QGridLayout,
                               QMainWindow, QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QSpacerItem,
                               QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout)
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        if not Form.objectName():
            Form.setObjectName(u"Form")
        Form.resize(417, 120)
        self.gridLayout_2 = QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName(u"gridLayout_2")
        self.label = QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        self.label.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 50))
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 2)

        self.pushButton = QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.pushButton_2 = QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(u"pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 1, 1, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Form", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"\u0412\u044b \u0443\u0432\u0435\u0440\u0435\u043d\u044b?", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"\u0414\u0430", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"\u041d\u0435\u0442", None))


class Widget(QWidget, Ui_Form): 
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(808, 510)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")

        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")

        self.frame = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setObjectName(u"frame")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        self.image_label = QLabel(alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.image_label.setObjectName(u"image_label")
        self.image_label.setPixmap(QPixmap("head3.png"))
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        lay.addWidget(self.image_label)

        self.widget = QWidget(self.image_label)
        self.widget.setObjectName(u"widget")

        self.formLayout = QFormLayout(self.widget)  # - (self.frame)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName(u"formLayout")

        self.pushButton = QPushButton()  # - (self.frame)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QSize(50, 30))
        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777214, 16777215))
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.pushButton)

        self.verticalSpacer = QSpacerItem(20, 250, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.formLayout.setItem(0, QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.verticalSpacer)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Test", None))


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        
        lbl = QLabel("please click something ...")
        buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(
            QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QDialogButtonBox.Apply)
            
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)            
        layout.addWidget(lbl)
        layout.addWidget(buttonBox)
        self.resize(100, 50)                                     
        
        applyBtn = buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Apply)
        applyBtn.clicked.connect(self.apply)
        cancelBtn = buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        cancelBtn.clicked.connect(self._reject)             
        
    def apply(self):
        print("Dialog: in apply") 

    def _reject(self): 
        self.reject()
        self.parent.close()    

    def closeEvent(self, event): 
        self.parent.close()


class Window(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)        
        self.setObjectName(u"window")

        self.dialog = Dialog(self)
        
        gridLayout = QGridLayout(self) 
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.dialog, 1, 1, 1, 1)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
        

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setupUi(self)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.create_dialog)  
        
    def create_dialog(self):
        self.window = Window(self)                        
        self.window.move(0, 0)
        self.window.resize(self.size()) 
        self.window.show()
        
        self.window.dialog.show()
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 


Stylesheet = """
#centralwidget {
    background-color:  rgb(37, 237, 37);
}
#frame {
    background-color:  rgb(37, 37, 237);
}

#pushButton {
    background-color: rgba(233, 33, 33, 0.7);
    color: #bfbfbf;
}
#image_label {
    background-color:  rgb(137, 137, 237);
}
#window {
    background-color: rgba(233, 33, 33, 0.5);
    color: #bfbfbf;
}
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)  
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> Я добавлю + за старательность, но к сожалению вы меня не правильно поняли, я хотел сделать такое же диалоговое окно но внутри одного окна, тоесть не отдельно 2ое, а всё в 1ом. Грубо говоря хотел покрыть элемент полупрозрачным серым цветом и отобразить поверх него диалог (виджет), всё в одном окне.

Вы отметили мой ответ не за старательность, а потому что уже сейчас или чуть позже мой ответ будет полезен для вас.

Я не уверен, что правильно понял, то что вы хотите сделать и мне кажется что мы об этом уже говорили. Попробуйте так.

```
import os
import sys
'''
from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QSize, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import QPixmap
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QFormLayout, QFrame, QGridLayout,
                               QMainWindow, QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QSpacerItem,
                               QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout)
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        if not Form.objectName():
            Form.setObjectName(u"Form")
        Form.resize(417, 120)
        self.gridLayout_2 = QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName(u"gridLayout_2")
        self.label = QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        self.label.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 50))
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 2)

        self.pushButton = QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.pushButton_2 = QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(u"pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 1, 1, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Form", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"\u0412\u044b \u0443\u0432\u0435\u0440\u0435\u043d\u044b?", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"\u0414\u0430", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"\u041d\u0435\u0442", None))


class Widget(QWidget, Ui_Form): 
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(808, 510)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")

        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")

        self.frame = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setObjectName(u"frame")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        self.image_label = QLabel(alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.image_label.setObjectName(u"image_label")
        self.image_label.setPixmap(QPixmap("head3.png"))
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        lay.addWidget(self.image_label)

        self.widget = QWidget(self.image_label)
        self.widget.setObjectName(u"widget")

        self.formLayout = QFormLayout(self.widget)  # - (self.frame)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName(u"formLayout")

        self.pushButton = QPushButton()  # - (self.frame)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QSize(50, 30))
        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777214, 16777215))
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.pushButton)

        self.verticalSpacer = QSpacerItem(20, 250, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.formLayout.setItem(0, QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.verticalSpacer)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Test", None))


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class Dialog(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        
        lbl = QLabel("please click something ...")
        lbl.setObjectName(u"lbl")
        buttonCancel = QPushButton('Cancel')
        buttonApply = QPushButton('Apply')
            
        layout = QGridLayout(self)            
        layout.addWidget(lbl, 0, 0, 1, 2, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(buttonCancel, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(buttonApply, 1, 1)

        buttonApply.clicked.connect(self.apply)
        buttonCancel.clicked.connect(self._reject)             
        
    def apply(self):
        print("Dialog: in apply") 

    def _reject(self): 
        self.parent.hide()    

    def closeEvent(self, event): 
        self.parent.hide()


class Window(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)        
        self.setObjectName(u"window")

        self.dialog = Dialog(self)
        self.dialog.setObjectName(u"dialog")
        
        gridLayout = QGridLayout(self) 
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.dialog, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        
        gridLayout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        gridLayout.setColumnStretch(1, 2)
        gridLayout.setColumnStretch(2, 1)
        gridLayout.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        gridLayout.setRowStretch(1, 2)
        gridLayout.setRowStretch(2, 1)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
        

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setupUi(self)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.create_dialog) 
        
        self.window = Window(self)
        self.window.hide()        
        
    def create_dialog(self):
        self.window.resize(self.size()) 
        self.window.show()
        
    def resizeEvent(self, event):                                    
        self.window.resize(self.size()) 
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 


Stylesheet = """
#centralwidget {
    background-color:  rgb(37, 237, 37);
}
#frame {
    background-color:  rgb(37, 37, 237);
}

#pushButton {
    background-color: rgba(233, 33, 33, 0.7);
    color: #bfbfbf;
}
#image_label {
    background-color:  rgb(137, 137, 237);
}
#window {
    background-color: rgba(233, 33, 33, 0.5);
    color: #bfbfbf;
}
#dialog {
    background-color: rgba(133, 133, 233, 0.7);
    color: #406343;
}
#lbl {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 22px;
}
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)  
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я добавлю + за старательность, но к сожалению вы меня не правильно поняли, я хотел сделать такое же диалоговое окно но внутри одного окна, тоесть не отдельно 2ое, а всё в 1ом. Грубо говоря хотел покрыть элемент полупрозрачным серым цветом и отобразить поверх него диалог (виджет), всё в одном окне.

Comment: @MRX я добавил обновление в свой ответ, проверьте.

Comment: То что надо, спасибо

Comment: @MRX пожалуйста.